# Allowing unauthenticated access to Laravel passport endpoint conditionally

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

We have passport authenticated Laravel endpoint. We want to give a seperate application from our main one the ability to call this specific endpoint without needing a user login, we also want to be able to identify the client. So for example two seperate client apps make an unauthenticated call to the endpoint and we could tell them apart by some means.

We've tried messing with custom guard & service providers, I'm under the impression passport makes it tricky to do what we want here.

We could just duplicate the endpoint and make one unauthenticated, I guess it's just tricky to understand how to structure things here to do what we want.

Comment: You could duplicate the route definition (i.e. the `Route::get` part) and have it use a different guard by specifying it different middleware. Of course this all really depends on your setup. Of course this implies that you would have a different endpoint for the other app, but that is not an uncommon solution to this kind of problem

Comment: Duplication of the endpoint is certainly something we've had a think about. I guess for us the question was how we could avoid that. It seems more and more likely we'll need to however.

Comment: I think it's just a lot more work involved in avoiding the duplication than in actually doing it. The problem I find is that it's a lot easier to deal with this using middleware but middleware is bound on the route.